# CocoaPods calendar view issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I found this CocoaPods [CalendarView](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Calendar-iOS) library written in Objective-c.

I use it in my Swift project as below:

```
guard let calendar = CalendarView(position: 0, y: 0) else { return }
self.view.addSubview(calendar)
```

The result I expect to see is below:

[image]

But I am getting days without a top part where year and month are displayed:

[image]

So I see the weekdays bar, days. But I would like to see the top bar too.

I tried setting mode to Default but it does not help.

EDITED:
When I enable headers as @Awais suggested I see overlay issue and calendar refresh resolve it.

[image]

Comment: is `shouldShowHeaders` set to true for calendar ? try setting that to true.. it might help.

Comment: @Awais thanks! looks like I also need to use calendar.refresh() because there is some layout overlaying issue in case I use calendar.shouldShowHeaders = true. Anyway thanks a lot. This is a direction I need to take a look and headers works now. Refreshing helps!

Comment: You are welcome! Yes, I did notice that there was a layout problem after showing headers is set to true. But I am glad that refresh works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `shouldShowHeaders` is no longer set to YES in the latest release of that pod when calendar view is loaded as shown in the screenshot below.

Setting the property `shouldShowHeaders` to `true` after creating the calendar instance should resolve this issue.

[Library Github](https://github.com/maximbilan/Calendar-iOS/blob/master/ios_calendar/ViewController.m)
[image]